# open and read a Sigmaplot .JNB file in Python

Tags: python, sigmaplot

My lab has a very large directory of Sigmaplot files, saved as .JNB . I would like to process the data in these files using Python. However, I have thus far been unable to read the files into anything interpretable.

I've already tried pretty much every numpy read function and most the panda read functions, and am getting nothing but gibberish.

Does anyone have any advice about reading these files short of exporting them all to excel one by one?

Comment: Can you export your `.JNB` file to a `.csv` or something similar?

Comment: I can export to excel, but as far as I've been able to figure out that has to be done one by one. They have literally thousands of files so I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, Sigmaplot is proprietary and seems a lot of people export to `.csv` to then use in `R` from what I can see. Also, this thread shows little hope: https://lists.debian.org/debian-science/2013/07/msg00014.html. My knowledge ends here :-(.

Comment: Thanks! It's more than I had before. I'm currently trying to talk my boss out of continuing to put our data in this format moving forward.